# Remove spaces within a string: "00 00 0" = "00000" in SQL

Tags: sql, trim

I'm dealing with 2 tables which hold NI Numbers, one stores them as "00 00 00 00 0" the other 000000000", I need to group by and other checks based on the NI Number across both tables.

Is there a way to trim the internal spaces? Or split the others up?

Comment: Use `REPLACE(ni, ' ', '')`, either in an `update` or in the query you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where REPLACE(foo.NiNumberWithSpaces,' ','') = bar.NiNumberWithNoSpaces
```